# JQuery carousel shift by one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create my own JQuery carousel using this code as example http://coolcodez.net/create-infinite-carousel-in-jquery-using-a-few-lines-of-code/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.fn.carousel = function () {
    var carousel = $(this);
    var width = carousel.find('li').width();
    setInterval(function() {
        carousel.delay(1000).animate({
            right: '+=' + width
        }, 1000, function () {
            var first = carousel.find('>:first-child');
            first.remove();
            $(this).append(first);
            $(this).css({
                right: '-=' + width
            });
        });
    }, 2000);

    return $(this);
};

    $('#carousel-1').carousel();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8b65qbb/33/

I need to shift one image to the left every time, but my script doesn't work properly.
How can I fix it and make it work the right way ?

Comment: Be more descriptive than "doesn't work". What is it doing wrong, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I need to get a one time shift was one item left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. First, I think the `carousel` variable should point to the `ul`, not to the `div`. The selector for the `first` variable is weird. Also, you should use `detach` instead of remove. By the way, there was a "jump" because you're not taking into account the margin between the list items in the animation.

Here's a working version (still needing big improvement):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.carousel = function () {
        var carousel = $(this);
        var width = carousel.find('li').width() + 15; // Hardcoded margin

        setInterval(function () {
            carousel.animate({
                right: '+=' + width
            }, 1000, function () {
                var first = carousel.find("li:first-child").detach();
                $(this).find("ul").append(first); // The "ul" should be cached
                $(this).css({
                    right: '-=' + width
                });
            });
        }, 2000);

        return $(this);
    };

    $('#carousel-1').carousel();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts and changes:

I would suggest to constrain your HTML and CSS to the really needed elements to achieve the desired, and that's `UL`. keep it minimalistic and simple:

```
<ul id="carousel-1" class="carousel clearfix">
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eTxMX2T.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VegKfUt.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
  </li>
</ul>
```

therefore that's the only needed CSS you need:

```
ul.carousel { 
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  height: 350px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:0;
}
ul.carousel li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

Regarding your plugin, this is a simple way to achieve the desired, looping a function instead of using a `setInterval`:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.carousel = function( options ) {

    return this.each(function() {
      var ul = this,
          w = $("li", ul).outerWidth(true);

      (function loop(){
        $(ul).delay(2000).animate({scrollLeft : w}, 700, function(){
          $(this).append( $('li:first', ul) ).scrollLeft(0);
          loop();
        });  
      }());

    }); 
  };
}(jQuery));
```

You can see from the code above that there's no hardcoded width values (beside the delay and animation, but on that later) cause of the use of `outerWidth(true);`which will account paddings, margins , borders of your LI element.

Now you're building a plugin, right? You might want to allow the user to easily modify default Plugin values like:

```
$('#carousel-1').carousel({
    pause : 3400,
    animate : 700
});
```

simply extend your plugin to accept editable options:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.carousel = function( options ) {

    var S = $.extend({ // Default Settings
      pause : 2000,
      speed : 700
    }, options );

    return this.each(function() {
      var ul = this,
          w = $("li", ul).outerWidth(true);

      (function loop(){
        $(ul).delay(S.pause).animate({scrollLeft : w}, S.speed, function(){
          $(this).append( $('li:first', ul) ).scrollLeft(0);
          loop();
        });  
      }());

    }); 
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.carousel = function( options ) {

    var S = $.extend({
      pause : 2000,
      speed : 700
    }, options );

    return this.each(function() {
      var ul = this,
          w = $("li", ul).outerWidth(true);

      (function loop(){
        $(ul).delay(S.pause).animate({scrollLeft : w}, S.speed, function(){
          $(this).append( $('li:first', ul) ).scrollLeft(0);
          loop();
        });  
      }());
      
    }); 
  };
}(jQuery));


$(function () { // DOM ready
  $('#carousel-1').carousel();
});
```

```css
ul.carousel { 
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  height: 350px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:0;
}
ul.carousel li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="carousel-1" class="carousel clearfix">
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eTxMX2T.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VegKfUt.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YrU0rrW.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eTxMX2T.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VegKfUt.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YrU0rrW.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Regarding a better UX, I would also sugget to pause completely your gallery on `mouseenter`, and restart your animations on `mouseleave` (though  a setInterval might be best suited in that case.)